# Lots of "multiple definitions" after toolchain reinstall

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I'm working on opensource ARDF transmitter (https://github.com/WhiteFossa/yiff-l) and currently working on firmware.

In firmware (written in C for STM32F103 using Eclipse Embedded CDT) I have a lot of .h files, they all are included into main.h, and then main.h included into all .c files.

This approach worked well, my code was compileable and so on.

Then I had to reinstall my Fedora for a some reason, and, of course, to reinstall toolchain, Eclipse and so on.

Now I get tons (1087 to be precise) error messages like this ones:

```
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `L2HAL_SSD1327_Context'; ./src/l2hal/src/l2hal.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/home/fossa/.local/xPacks/@xpack-dev-tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/10.2.1-1.1.2/.content/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./src/stm32f1xx_it.o (symbol from plugin): in function `NMI_Handler':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `I2C_Other'; ./src/l2hal/src/l2hal.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/home/fossa/.local/xPacks/@xpack-dev-tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/10.2.1-1.1.2/.content/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./src/stm32f1xx_it.o (symbol from plugin): in function `NMI_Handler':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `I2C_Display'; ./src/l2hal/src/l2hal.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:87: Yiff-HL.elf] Error 1
"make -j all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

14:31:50 Build Failed. 1087 errors, 4 warnings. (took 1s.30ms)
```

Could someone help me with this problem?

Is it a problem with a code (and my way of including)? Or, maybe, something wrong with compiler/linker setup?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. Then come back and [edit] your question to show us the command line the leads to the errors. This is apparently the linker's call. It seems as if `stm32f1xx_it` implements a lot of same things as `l2hal`.

Comment: `and then main.h included into all .c files` and then, other file included `main.h` so compiled `.c` files all again. Remove all your `.c` includes and never include a `.c` file.

Comment: _"Is it a problem with a code (and my way of including)?"_ : possibly, but you have not shown that, only described it (somewhat ambiguously).  What the linker is telling you in this fragment is that symbols in  src/l2hal/src/l2hal.o also appear in src/stm32f1xx_it.o. At a guess I'd say you have included a .c file instead of using _separate compilation and linking_.

Comment: Apart from that including all possible headers in one single header is a bad idea and hard to maintain.  It will lead to extended build times both because the compiler has to process the mammoth header for every unit, but also because every module is then dependent on every header, so any header change will cause all units to be compiled, defeating any opportunity for an incremental build.

Comment: What were the four warnings? Fix those first.

Comment: It seems that it's a problem with my code, which appeared after switching from one compiler version to another.

Rewriting it now in a such way:
1) Created GlobalVariables.h, where global variables placed
2) Using extern TypeName VariableName; when global variable is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all commenters, will see soon, if rewritten code work. If it will, I'll post a link to commit with a fix.